# Handling CORS policy for multiple environment in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to "toggle" between my CORS policies depending on the environment the application is running.

I have two policies declared as follows:

```cs
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(CORSPolicies.PublicApi,
        builder => builder
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .WithMethods("POST", "GET")
            .WithOrigins("https://domain1.com", "https://domain2.com"));

    options.AddPolicy(CORSPolicies.Dev,
        builder => builder
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyOrigin());
});
```

These policies should be only applicable to a few controllers so I'm using the attribute to apply them:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[EnableCors(CORSPolicies.PublicApi)]
public class PublicApiControllerBase : ControllerBase
{
}
```

`PublicAPI` policy should be valid for production where domains are going to actually be restricted. `Dev` policy allows anything since I'll be using it locally.

I tried to set the default policy to be `Dev` conditionally on the application start, but since `EnableCorsAttribute` overrides what is defined by `app.UseCors()` it didn't work as `PublicApi` policy will be used no matter what. Here's my naive attempt:

```cs
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseCors(CORSPolicies.Dev);
}
else
{
    app.UseCors();
}
```

How can I a) make my `PublicApi` policy behave differently depending on the environment my app is running or b) conditionally apply `PublicApi` or `Dev` policy depending on the environment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For option A, you can inject `IWebHostEnvironment` into the `Startup` constructor, capture it as a field, and use it in `ConfigureServices`.

Here's what that looks like:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment env;

    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        this.env = env;
    }

    public void ConfigureService(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(CORSPolicies.PublicApi, builder =>
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyOrigin();
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                        .WithMethods("POST", "GET")
                        .WithOrigins("https://domain1.com", "https://domain2.com");
                }
            });
        });

        // ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // ...

        app.UseCors();

        // ....
    }
}
```

This uses a single CORS policy, `CORSPolicies.PublicApi`, which is configured according to the environment.